# How to make routerLink go to a different link when active?

Tags: angular

Using angular2/4/5/6 router, I have multiple links:

```
<a [routerLink]="/page1" [routerLinkActive]="class here">Link 1</a>
<a [routerLink]="/page2" [routerLinkActive]="class here">Link 2</a>
<a [routerLink]="/page3" [routerLinkActive]="class here">Link 3</a>
```

This link is available on all pages in a 'FrameComponent', where there is a router-outlet on the page that changes. I want to make it so that if the user clicks on "Link 1" and goes to the route /page1... then click son "Link 1" again, instead of trying to go to "/page1", it goes to "/welcomepage". This should apply to every single link on the page.

For example, if the user clicks /page2, it will take them to that route and the link is 'active', though if the user clicks on the "Link 2" again, then it takes them back to the "/welcomepage" route.

If the user clicks on the link taking them to /page2, if the user tries click on "link 1", then it will take them to "/page1". It is only if the user has already activated a route, in which the button that has the routerLink would redirect the user to navigate to "/welcomepage" if they clicked that same button.

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
 <a [routerLink]="/page1" [routerLinkActive]="class here">Link 1</a>
```

Go for

```
<a (click)=“navigate('page1')” [routerLinkActive]="class here">Link</a>
```

And write the logic in navigate function. Whether to change the route to page1 if the current route is not page1 and to homePage if the current route is of page1

**EDIT**
Sample code for navigate method -

```
// Import Router and provide it in the cosntructor as router
public navigate(path: string): void {
    if(this.router.url.includes(path) {
        this.router.navigate(['/welcomepage']);
    } else {
        this.router.navigate([`/${path}`]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show what this function would look like to handle the navigation?

Comment: Is there some way to trigger routerLinkActive class active programatically to highlight if active and unhighlight if "clicked again while it is active"? Seems complicated if I have say 10 links and I have to have an array to keep track of each one.

Answer (score 0):

```
<li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/page1']">Link 1</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/page2']">Link 2</a>
</li>
<li class="nav-item" routerLinkActive="active">
    <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="['/page3']">Link 3</a>
</li>
```